# error al email, hosting en azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, azure

Tengo problemas al enviar un reporte por email, de manera local funciona muy bien, pero al publicarlo en **`Azure`** no funciona.

```
string deDireccionOrigen = "UniversidadCentral@gmail.com";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    UserName = deDireccionOrigen,
    Password = "mipasSecreto" 
};

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(deDireccionOrigen);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(alumno.CorreoElectronico));
message.Subject = "Solicidud de Tramite";
message.IsBodyHtml = true; 
message.Body = GeneraCuerpoCorreo(alumno.NombreCompleto);

//documento adjunto
var docAdjunto = GeneraDocumentoAdjunto(alumno, ObternerConstanciaNombre(tipoDocumentoId));
message.Attachments.Add(docAdjunto);

smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

El error dice:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection
>   or the client was not authenticated. The server response was:
>   5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at...

¿Alguien tiene experiencia publicando en ***Azure***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que vas a tener que evaluar alternativas distinta, como ser el envio de mail utilizando el servicio de `SendGrid`

[Envío de correos electrónicos con SendGrid y Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)

en el articulo comenta

> Los clientes de Azure pueden desbloquear 25.000 correos electrónicos gratuitos cada mes.

lo habilitas desde el portal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el codigo agregas la referencia a la libreria desde nuget

[SendGrid nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid)

ya que el mail se envia usando la api del servicio

```
var msg = new SendGridMessage();

msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("dx@example.com", "SendGrid DX Team"));

var recipients = new List<EmailAddress>
{
    new EmailAddress("jeff@example.com", "Jeff Smith"),
    new EmailAddress("anna@example.com", "Anna Lidman"),
    new EmailAddress("peter@example.com", "Peter Saddow")
};
msg.AddTos(recipients);

msg.SetSubject("Testing the SendGrid C# Library");

msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, "Hello World plain text!");
msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, "<p>Hello World!</p>");
```

Comment: gracias @leandro tenias razon

Answer (score 2):

Mas allá de lo que menciona Leandro, el problema seguramente es que autenticaste la conexión local en GMail, pero no la remota (Azure).

Si vas a seguir utilizando este método, desde las configuraciones de seguridad de la cuenta de GMail correspondiente a la dirección que utilices habilitar el envío de mails desde fuentes externas y habilitar el host de azure.

Este link te va a ayudar: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=es